# Boxes cant resize after the most biggest one

Tags: html, css

I want to set all of these boxes `width` and `height` after the most biggest one.. `display: flex` destroy whole card.

Can someone tell me what change, what add or what to do, to let that code still working?

CSS

```
.profile {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.profile a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

.profile_name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color:rgb(5, 148, 0);
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="profile">
            <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
            <div class="profile_name">Name</div>
            <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
            <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
        <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
        <div class="profile_name">Administrator Adminovsky</div>
        <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
        <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more so I can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly what your actual problem is. But I'll try anyway...

How about including all .profile elements in a container div and replace max-width with just width? Also .profile:hover will be best to scale to 1.05.

```css
.profiles-container {
  widht: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.profile {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
}

.profile a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

.profile_name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color:rgb(5, 148, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="profiles-container">    
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
    <div class="profile_name">Name</div>
    <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
    <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
   </div>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
      <div class="profile_name">Administrator Adminovsky</div>
      <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
      <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think you are mistaken to consider finding the bigger one. You just have to decide on a size that fits what you want to do and going with it. You can then adjust the child elements of profile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a little bit of **JS**, in this snippet I used two `forEach` cycles for the profiles, the first is used to detect the maximum width and height of each `profile`, and the second is applying it to all `profile` elements. So all the profile elements have the maximum width and height.

```js
let profiles = document.querySelectorAll(".profile"),
    profileWidth = 0,
    profileHeight = 0;
    
profiles.forEach(function(profile){
  if(profile.offsetHeight > profileHeight){
    profileHeight = profile.offsetHeight;
    }
   if(profile.offsetWidth > profileWidth){
    profileWidth = profile.offsetWidth;
    }
});

profiles.forEach(function(profile){
    profile.style.height = profileHeight + "px";
    profile.style.width = profileWidth + "px";
});
```

```css
.profile {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.profile a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

.profile_name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color:rgb(5, 148, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
            <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
            <div class="profile_name">Name</div>
            <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
            <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
<div class="profile">
        <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
        <div class="profile_name">Administrator Adminovsky</div>
        <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
        <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex attribute but is not related to your question

in my opinion you must use JavaScript or other scripts to do that

in JavaScript:

1-get All boxes

2-find the biggest

3-set Other boxes with and height

but its will be nice by using :
css:

```
body {
    display: flex;
 }
 .profile {
    flex: 1;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.profile a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

.profile_name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
color:rgb(5, 148, 0);
}
```

html:

```
<div className="profile">
<img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" className="profile_image">
    <div className="profile_name">Name</div>
    <div className="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
    <div className="profile_verifed"><i className="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
</div>
<div className="profile">
<img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" className="profile_image">
    <div className="profile_name">Administrator Adminovsky</div>
    <div className="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
    <div className="profile_verifed"><i className="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
</div>
```

or use JavaScript :

```js
var boxes = $(".profile");
var maxWidth = 0;
boxes.each((index,data)=>{
if(maxWidth<$(data).width())
  maxWidth = $(data).width()
});
boxes.each((index,data)=>{
  console.log(maxWidth);
$(data).width(maxWidth);
});
```

```css
.profile {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    float: left;
    transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.profile a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

.profile_name {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color:rgb(5, 148, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile">
            <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
            <div class="profile_name">Name</div>
            <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
            <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
        <img src="default.jpg" alt="Profile photo" class="profile_image">
        <div class="profile_name">Administrator Adminovsky</div>
        <div class="profile_info">Men (12 years)</div>
        <div class="profile_verifed"><i class="material-icons">check</i>Verifed</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The JavaScript option isn't working. It's showing me the same thing as the code in the question.

Comment: @VlastimilLisák this code using jQuery. don't forget add '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'
 in your html .like example

Comment: Oh yes, I'm so sorry, don't know how I could overlook this.

Comment: No, it's not my question :P :D I'm the other one answering.